# How do you use the "Bytes" data type in Google Firestore in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) seems to suggest that Google Firestore supports storing binary data with the "Bytes" data type. How do you do that using the [official client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php)? I have tried the code below and get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Expect utf-8 encoding.`

```
$compressed = gzcompress('Hello World');

$firestoreClient = $eaapen->firestore->client;

$firestoreClient->collection('test')->newDocument()->set([
    'data' => $compressed
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add bytes type data to Firestore directly. [you will have to create a blob](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore/blob/master/src/FirestoreClient.php) with something like:

$blob = $firestoreClient->blob('yourfile'));

Then add it to your Firestore. But really this is not a good idea as there is a hard limit of [1 MiB for a document in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) and you can hit it easily with bytes data.

I would highly suggest using [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) for such cases.